# How to request url of that model detail views in search result?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am searching in three model and all model has different detail views and but i am unable to figure out how to tell django to locate the view acc to their model
this is my view for seaching in models

def search_item(request):
results = []
search_item = request.GET.get("search")

```
if search_item:
    q = Q(title__icontains=search_item) | Q(written_by__icontains=search_item)
    for model in (crypto, News, Movie):
        results.extend(model.objects.filter(q))

return render(request, "result.html", {"results": results})
```

and for that template

```
{% for result in results %}
  <a class="blog-card" href="">
    <div class="card col-4" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="{{ result.title_image.url }}" class="card-img-top" width="100%" height="200px">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-center" style="color:black">{{ result.title|truncatewords:7 }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text text-center" style="color:black">{{ result.info|truncatewords:10 }}</p>
        <p class="number text-center" style="color: black;"> Wriiten By:<strong> {{ result.written_by }}</strong></p>
        <p class="last text-center" style="color: black;"> Last update:<strong> {{ result.joined_date }}</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```

and all the model has different detail views, so how to do that
urls.py

```
  path('crypto/<slug:title>/',views.ttt_read,name="ttt_read"),
    path('news/<slug:title>/',views.news_read,name="news_read"),
    path('movie/<slug:title>/',views.movie_read,name="movie_read"),
    path('penmen/search/',views.search_item,name='search')
```

any help and suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each model define a `get_absolute_url()` method.

Example:

```
    from django.urls import reverse

    class News(models.Model):
        ...
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('news_read', args=[slug(self.title)])

Then in your template you can just do:

    ...
    <a class="blog-card" href="{{result.get_absolute_url}}">
    ...
```

Comment: i already used that but after seeing your i again tried it then it work anyway thank you so much